# Making all s3 files in a folder public with boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a bunch of files in an S3 bucket which all need to be **public**. However, as new files are added there by my teammates, they forget to set them to public.

So, I'm using a python3 script to make sure all the respective files are made public.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')

## Bucket to use
bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')

## List objects within a given prefix
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='public_folder/'):
    obj.set_acl('public-read')
```

When I try the above I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute 'set_acl'
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the object acl first and edit it

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket_name','object_key')
response = object_acl.put(ACL='public-read')
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to **make the whole bucket public** (or even just a subdirectory *within* the bucket), the easier method is to **create a Bucket Policy** like this example from [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html):

> The following example policy grants the s3:GetObject permission to any public anonymous users. This permission allows anyone to read the object data, which is useful for when you configure your bucket as a website and want everyone to be able to read objects in the bucket. Before you use a bucket policy to grant read-only permission to an anonymous user, you must **disable block public access settings for your bucket**.

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This will grant public access regardless of the ACL setting on the individual objects.